# How to call hook function with arguments

Tags: wordpress

In my theme php file I have this hook:

```
<?php bp_nouveau_member_hook( 'before', 'header_meta' ); ?>
```

It must be untouched, I can not change it.

How can I pass text „Hello world“ to this place from functions.php?

I was trying to do this:

```
function greeting($before,  $header_meta){

 $before = "Hello world";
 $header_meta = "Hello world";

}

add_action( 'bp_nouveau_member_hook_before', 'greeting', 10, 2  );
```

But it does not work.

Comment: "bp_nouveau_member_hook" is not like a hook. its function.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by

```
add_action( 'bp_before_member_header_meta', 'greeting', 10, 0 );
```